# RandomForest categorical variables error in R

Tags: r, error-handling, random-forest

I am currently trying to run a RandomForest model on a predictor set of 40 variables.

37 are numeric, 3 are categorical

When I try to run the RandomForest, I receive an error:

```
Error in { : 
  task 1 failed - "non-numeric variable in data frame: City.GroupTypeCity.disc"
```

All factors have levels of 32 or less. I know RandomForest can handle categorical predictors so what is wrong here?

Comment: If you want some help, provide at least some code and/or data.

Comment: Could it be that one or more of your variables are character variables? Check the class and set to categorical (as.factor) if needed.